# How to override nginx upstream response code?

Tags: nginx

I've got some nginx boxes used as reverse proxies to our app infra, the normal config for each app is essentially:

```
geo $fooapp {
  default fooapp;
}

upstream fooapp {
  server ...
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://$fooapp;
    ...
  }
}
```

Now when we need to take the apps down for maintenance we've got a single `maintenance.conf` that currently simply defines:

```
upstream maintenance {
  server 1.2.3.4:443;
}
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is a simple HTTP server serving a static maintenance page. There's a little background logic that pulls in status messages, but it just overwrites a plain HTML page served statically.

Then we update each app's `geo` block like:

```
geo $fooapp {
  default maintenance;
  10.0.0.0/16 fooapp;
  ...
}
```

Which allows our staff to run tests and generally muck about with the apps without it being publicly visible.

Now where we're running into trouble is that some of these proxied routes themselves contain API endpoints, and if someone had one of our apps open before we turned on maintenance mode the client-side code will still be making API requests. Now these API requests get caught in the blanket maintenance, routed to the `maintenance` upstream, and get a `200` response with an HTML body instead of the JSON they're expecting.

What I would like to do is alter the response code served by the `maintenance` upstream to be a 503. This would send the proper signal to browsers/crawlers/etc that the application is temporarily unavailable, and also trigger proper error-handling within the client-side code.

I know that this is definitely outside the scope of the `upstream` block config, so I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
upstream maintenance_actual {
  server 1.2.3.4:443;
}

server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8443;
  location / {
    override_status_code 503; #totally made up
    proxy_pass https://maintenance_actual
  }
}

upstream maintenance {
  server 127.0.0.1:8443;
}
```

but I can't seem to find something that will modify the response code like this.

I'm not particularly inclined to change the config on the server serving the maintenance page to always return a 503, as that would obscure whether or not that that server is having an issue itself.